# basic functionnalities doesn't work for firestore security

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to secure my Firestore database with the integrated code editor in the firebase website. My aim is to check before reading document called "moyenne", if:

numr == request.auth.token.phone_number || numr in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Profil/$(request.auth.token.phone_number).resource.data.numbers

I tried this:

```
   //first try    
   match /Note/{numr}/moyenne/moyenne {
  allow read:
    if (numr == request.auth.token.phone_number || numr in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Profil/$(request.auth.token.phone_number)).resource.data.numbers);
}
  //second try
match /Note/{numr}/moyenne/moyenne {
  allow read:
    if (numr == request.auth.token.phone_number || 
    numr in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Profil/$(path(request.auth.token.phone_number))).resource.data.numbers);
}
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Error for the first try (the test number is +91909090909):
Call the [get] function with a path to a non-existing resource: / databases /% 28default% 29 / documents / Profile /% 2B33651177261

Error for the second try:
Error: simulator.rules line [14], column [17]. Property resource is undefined on object.

PS: structure of the profil document:
[image: structure of the profil document:]

Comment: You might want to edit your question to show the exact contents of the referenced parts of the database so we can follow along with what the rules are actually referencing.  Right now we're having to guess what the document read by each get() actually contains.

Comment: I have updated my post.